# Whether we can use auto increment as well as manual insertion in hibernate for primary key

Tags: hibernate

I have scenario for the primary key column, auto increment should happen. Sometimes I have to set manually.In hibernate its possible ?

If possible please help what annotation should I use.

Comment: Why would you have to set it manually some times, and not others? You can just set the Id you want to use, yes.

Comment: ok, I will in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible if you are using the `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE` you can always go ahead and change the sequence in database. 
In the below code I have created the sequence `instructor_id_sequ`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "instructor_id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "instructor_id_generator", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 101, sequenceName = "instructor_id_sequ")
@Column(name="INSTRUCTOR_ID")
private int instructorId;
```

Below is the sequence you can check in DB and can either re-create or alter the same. [I am using Oracle10]

[image: Oracle Sequence]